# FTP transfer all files in a remote directory, and tweak permissions, using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, download

How can I download folder from some ftp server into my server home directory and give to that directory rights (like all files in this directory have all or no rights)?

Not using special libraries if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
file_put_contents('./file.txt', file_get_contents('ftp://server/file.txt'));
?>
```

The FTP server must support passive mode ([ref](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php)) and your web server must have `allow_url_fopen` set in the php.ini ([ref](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)).

To give rights use `chmod('./file.txt', 0777)` or whatever rights you need.

Comment: +1 for clear concise explanation, supporting comments and elegant ref links

Comment: But ... this is for transferring text.  I figured the question was about files.  ?

Comment: I guess it's good for anything -- both file functions are binary safe, I just used a .txt file as an example.

Comment: grate about file's (at leastone - it was what I realy needed - I get zip and unpac it) But Question was about "... download folder from ..." so I suppoused to get all folder not knowing what files are exactly in it....

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want PHP's functions for FTP such as **ftp_nlist** and **ftp_nb_get**:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ref_ftp.asp

I also found this resource which looks like a good tutorial as well as usable code:

http://www.raditha.com/php/ftp/pasv.php