# How to transferer a folder to ftp from another ftp in php?

Tags: php, ftp

I have to websites, and I want to transferer the files on the folder in website 1 to another folder in the website 2. How can I do that using php?

Thanks!

So, I want to transfer, not Copy. Transferer means get all the files in a folder and move to other ftp in another folder there. For example.

In FTP 1:

```
 /folder1/file.txt
 /folder1/file2.txt
 /folder1/file3.txt
```

In FTP 2:

```
      /MyFiles/
```

I want to transferer the files.txt in FTP 1 to FTP 2, so the result will be:

In FTP 1:

```
   /folder1/
```

In FTP2:

```
/MyFiles/file.txt
/MyFiles/file2.txt
/MyFiles/file3.txt
```

How can I do that using php?

I tried:

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "./folder1"); 
foreach ($contents as $file) { 

        ftp_get($conn_id, $file, "MyFiles/".$file, FTP_BINARY); 
        echo $file;
}
```

Comment: With `copy("ftp://.../file", "ftp2://");` including `user:pw@` for instance. Or use the [`ftp_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) extension.

Comment: Could you show me an example please?

Comment: Its not duplicated, I want to transferer not copy, and its a lot of files inside a folder to another..

Comment: Well, share your prior research and attempts; explain the difference between transfer and copy, and where exactly your issues lie.

Comment: Then open the source [`ftp`](http://php.net/ftp) connection, read the filenames per [`ftp_nlist`](http://php.net/ftp_nlist), loop over said list, use either  [`ftp_get`](http://php.net/ftp_get) (src) and [`ftp_put`](http://php.net/ftp_put) (dest) or simply the PHP stream functions (copy) to transfer each file, and afterwards delete the original on the source server using `ftp_delete()`. [Note: I'm not writing scripts.]

Comment: I tried something like that based on this script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650439/downloading-a-folder-through-with-ftp-using-php but The types of my files are not equal when transferer