# ftp_get parent name and just some subfolders

Tags: php, ftp

i use ftp_get to download my ftp files from my server to my laptop. and i want  to download just somes dirs and files but under the parent name
for example i have a folder **public_html** contains 3 folder  A and B and C. i want to get just the A Folder but also the parent which is **public_html** im looking for this result :  **public_html/A**. i mean i want to download the **parent**/**child**
this is my code :

```
ftp_get($conn_id, "public_html/A", "public_html/A", FTP_BINARY);
```

i get only the sub folder **A**

Comment: And what problem do you have with your task? The `ftp_get` can download one specific file only. So you you have to download files one by one. So I do not see what problem you may have with downloading only the file that you want.

Comment: yes but i want to download A and public_html i mean the parent and the child

Comment: What do you mean by "download A"? Do you mean files in "A"? Or the "empty" parent folder "A"?

Comment: i want to to download public_html and the A folder

Comment: Sorry, you keep repeating the same vague sentence. What's your problem? There are many posts here on downloading folders. For example [Downloading a folder through with FTP using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5650439/850848).